# Stop Refreshing Page When Wordpress Commenting

Tags: wordpress

**Stop refreshing page when commenting**

i want to stop refreshing when anyone commenting or do reply on comments. Is it possible? Please help me.

**Other questions to you:**

Is there any function for must use post thumbnail in wordpress?

see my Previews question here: [I want to show all of my title on same position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814559/i-want-to-show-all-of-my-title-on-same-position)

waiting to your better response

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin - it should do everything you need.

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-ajax-comments/